# Azure Bot Service Facebook Messenger Callback URL gives 404

Tags: facebook, azure, callback, botframework, messenger

I have created a bot that I host in Azure and works fine for all the other channels I have enabled, including SFB, consumer skype, email, SMS, Teams, etc.  The only channel I can't complete is the Facebook Messenger channel as the callback URL generated by Azure does not work.  I get a 404 error, which is what Facebook also responds back with and doesn't let me proceed.  I've tried disabling and re-enabling which has no effect and the URL doesn't change.  Please help me figure out how to get the URL working.

https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/TrinityBP

Thanks!

Comment: if you are still having problems, please report it here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

Are you enabled WebHook in your app facebook?
You have to configure the permission on web API in your facebook application, for example:

Navigate: https://developers.facebook.com

Mi apps -> my bot ->Advance Configuration-> Security

Set "Allow API access to application settings" to YES

and try it!

Comment: Yes, I have done that step, but the step required of putting in the callback URL to Facebook fails as the URL produces a 404.

Comment: So the step you are talking about is the exact step I can't complete because the callback URL is giving a 404.

Comment: per -nilsw, I have added issue to GitHub.